# Xamarin Forms conditional formatting within a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

In the code-behind of the parent page, how do we say,

```
foreach(label in the ListView)
{
   if(label.Text == "something")
   {
        //do some formatting
   }
}
```

I think this should be in the override of OnAppearing but I'm not sure of the syntax.

thanks

UPDATE:
In response to comments, the ListView has 2 labels, I want to say, if label1 = "x", do specific formatting on label2.

Hope that's a bit clearer

Comment: Uncear. You want to change each cell of a listview after it's rendered?  Maybe if you elaborate you specific case, we can help. Often behaviors and/or converters are enough to handle this kind of need, but for now your question seems too broad.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the SetupContent(Cell, Index) and performing the formatting there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property in `ListView` named `TemplatedItems` that return a `ViewCell` and we can get from this ViewCell all views that we have (if you use template may it will be a little bit different).

```
    foreach (ViewCell myViewCell in mylist.TemplatedItems)
    {

        Label myLabel = (Label) myViewCell.View;
        if (myLabel.Text == "smth")
        {
            //do some formatting

        }
    }
```

Comment: seems like what I need thanks, get an .InvalidCastException on the Label myLabel line, but I'm sure I'll work it out...

Comment: This mean that you have many Views inside the ViewCell you can work with them using different properties, example if you have a grid inside it you need to cast it to grid first after that get Children(Label) from this grid. i advice to debug and see the value of myViewCell and the structure this will make it more easy